# Batch file perform task in directories recursively when the directory name contains "&"

Tags: batch-file, recursion

I made a batch program to perform some simple tasks in directories recursively and it usually works without problems. but if the directory name contains "&", I got an error.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "exitCode=0"
    set "BaseDir=%~1"

    if not defined BaseDir set "BaseDir=%CD%"

    for %%f in ("%BaseDir%") do set "BaseDir=%%~ff"

    if not exist "%BaseDir%" (
        call :error "Base directory does not exist"
        goto endProcess
    )

    call :recursive "%BaseDir%"
    if errorlevel 1 set "exitCode=1"

    goto :endProcess

:Whattodo

    echo %CD%
    goto :eof

:recursive BaseDir
    setlocal
    set "BaseDir=%~f1"
    pushd "%BaseDir%"
    for /d %%d in (*) do if not errorlevel 1 call :recursive "%%~fd"
    call :Whattodo
    popd
    endlocal
    goto :eof

:error
    echo(%~1
    set "exitCode=1" & cmd /d /q /c exit /b 1
    goto :eof

:endProcess
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

I will get a output like this:

```
C:\tmp\01\04
C:\tmp\01\05
C:\tmp\01
C:\tmp\02\06
C:\tmp\02\07\08
C:\tmp\02\07
C:\tmp\02
C:\tmp\03
C:\tmp
```

but if I have a directory like this "C:\tmp\02\06 & a" I will have this output

```
C:\tmp\01\04
C:\tmp\01\05
C:\tmp\01
C:\tmp\02\06
'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
C:\tmp\02
C:\tmp
```

I understand that the problem is in the line below, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
for /d %%d in (*) do if not errorlevel 1 call :recursive "%%~fd"
```

!! edit

Before I posted it I tried what I can to debug the error. `echo %CD%` just print the current directory, to help me debug. Could be `cd` and the error will persist. (I tried)

What I could find out, the variable `"%%~fd"` is expanded and than the line is processing. 
In this way call pass `"C:\tmp\02\06"` (instead of `"C:\tmp\02\06 & a"`) and try to execult the command `a`

Comment: Could the problem be in your `:Whattodo` subroutine?  Try replacing `echo %CD%` with `cd` and see if that gets rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Like rojo said, your problem is located in the `:Whattodo` function.

Replace `echo %CD%` with `echo !CD!` and it should work.
As percent expansion is vulnerable to special characters, but delayed expansion isn't.
If you don't want to enable it always, you can enabled it only in the function.

```
:Whattodo
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo !CD!
    endlocal
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Heya jeb!  LTNS.  Anyway, I think you meant `echo !cd!` in your example code. But why not just `cd` to print the working dir?

Comment: @rojo Thanks for the edit. A simple CD would work also, but I wanted to show how use the delayed expansion here